# Table cell's content view is being shifted to the left if an accessory is added in IB

Tags: ios

I've got a custom table view cell defined within a nib, I'm finding that whatever colour I set for view background in IB isn't being applied (why its not being applied is another question I have). So within the table view controller I added:

```
[localCell.contentView setBackgroundColor:LIGHT_BACKGROUND];
```

The cell colour now comes out as expected, however if in IB I set the accessory to anything other than none then the colour of the cell is shifted to the left by an amount about equal to the size of the indicator, behind the indicator I can see the background colour for the table.

Why is this happening?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accessory view is not contained within the content view.  You probably need to set the color of the background view of your cell rather than the content view.

```
[localCell.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:LIGHT_BACKGROUND];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however if I set this then nothing appears for the colour of the cell - its transparent (though I have opaque set on in the view section of IB). Any idea why this is?